# What is the opposite of heterotopia?

Tags: foucault

Michel Foucault's [essay](https://web.mit.edu/allanmc/www/foucault1.pdf) on heterotopias mentions the other real sites - where social order is maintained - that are "represented, contested, and inverted" by heterotopias. What exactly are these real sites in Foucalt? Are they utopias? If heterotopias exist, what is the rest of the world in relation to them?

Comment: See [Heterotopia (space)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterotopia_(space)). And see F's text: "We do not live inside a void that could be colored with diverse shades of light, we live inside a set of relations that delineates sites which are irreducible to one another and absolutely not superimposable on one another. Of course one might attempt to describe these different sites by looking for the set of relations by which a given site can be deﬁned.  1/2

Comment: For example, describing the set of relations that deﬁne the sites of transportation, streets, trains (a train is an extraordinary bundle of relations because it is something through which one goes, it is also something by means of which one can go from one point to another, and then it is also something that goes by). One could describe, via the cluster of relations that allows them to be deﬁned, the sites of temporary relaxation —cafes, cinemas, beaches. Likewise one could describe, via its network of relations, the closed or semi-closed sites of rest — the house, the bedroom, the bed." 2/2